# Distinguish SHA-1 and SHA-2

Tags: encryption, sha

We got a programm which encrypts data and need to know wether it's using SHA-1 or SHA-2. Unfortunately the only hint is a table with hash values.
Can someone please tell me how I can distinguish the two encryption types and tell which one is used here?

Answer (score 2):

> We got a programm which encrypts data and need to know wether it's using SHA-1 or SHA-2.

I assume you mean that you're hashing data. SHA is a family of hashing algorithms, not encryption algorithms.

The primary way you would distinguish is their lengths. SHA-1 is 160 bits (20 bytes). SHA-2 comes in several forms, from 224 to 512 bits (28-64 bytes). Note that there are some truncated versions of SHA-2, so it can be difficult to be certain exactly which one is being used, but they're all longer than SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean hashing not encryption. encryption is reversible, hashing is not, encryption is like random permutation as opposed to hash which tries to be like a random function. 
SHA-1 is 160bit (20 bytes) long, while SHA-2 is a family of hash functions 224-512 bits long (28-32 bytes). 
Note you may have hex-encoding or base64 encoding which will give you 4 or 6 bits per encoded character. 
In some cases (for example password hashing) it is customary to prefix hashes with information on how they were created and you would see hash strings start with some special prefix such as $1$ which tells you what you are looking at.

If you do not have an extra prefix and have the data truncated to the same length, and you do not know anything about the input before the hashing I do not believe you can discern between the two by any practical means. An ability to tell the difference between SHA-1 and truncated SHA-2 would mean at least one of them can be separated from random data which we require secure cryptographic functions to be undistingishable from. 
I am unaware of a practical distinguishing attack.

Regardless of computational complexity you can't tell where a single hash came from with high probability since most hashes have a pre-image also from the other function.